# Enabling SSL for a website

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to enable SSL on my local computer for an asp.net 4.0 web site. What steps do I need to take? I want to use a free SSL certificate.

Comment: Googling "asp.net ssl" gives a *ton* of results.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for development purposes with Visual Studio 2010 SP1:

1. Install [IIS Express 7.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb).
2. Open your web project in Visual Studio 2010.
3. Right click the project and select "Use IIS Express".
4. Select the project in the soultion explorer and open the properties window (don't right click and open properties, you need the properties window that you can get with pressing `F4` by default, used with the designer usually)
5. Set `SSL Enabled` to true.

If this is for serving web pages outside of development, that entirely depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SSL on your localhost for testing, use a self signed cert.

[Self Signed Cert](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Enabling SSL in IIS on Windows XP Professional](http://www.somacon.com/p41.php)

[Enabling SSL in IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2006](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/mindtouch_setup/040Advanced_Configuration/IIS/Enabling_SSL_on_IIS_6)

[Enabling SSL on IIS 7.0 on Windows Vista/7 Using Self-Signed Certificates](http://mscrm4humans.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/enabling-ssl-on-iis-7-0-using-self-signed-certificates/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's info on free SSL / TSL solution:
https://www.startssl.com/

Haven't tried this myself, but documentation etc. seems to be OK.